# Error creating twitter ACAccount on iOS5: NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios5, accounts

I am having trouble creating and saving a new twitter account to `ACAccountStore` on iOS5.

After performing all the steps to init the account, `ACAccountStore's` `saveAccount:withCompletionHandler:` returns `NSURLErrorDomain error -1012`.

Does anyone have similar issues?

My code sample below is using requestToken to init `ACAccountCrendential`. This object is an `OAToken` (ShareKit object) initialized with the token and secret received from twitter after completing `OAuth`.

```
    ACAccountStore *store = [[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] autorelease];
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    ACAccount *account = [[[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:twitterAccountType] autorelease];

    account.username = @"twitterusername";
    account.credential = [[[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:requestToken.key tokenSecret:requestToken.secret] autorelease]; 
    [store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            [store saveAccount:account withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if (success) {
                    NSLog(@"TWITTER ACCOUNT CREATED SUCCESSFULLY!");
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"ERROR creating twitter account: %@", [error description]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```

The strange thing is that Apple's [Accounts Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/AccountsFrameworkRef.pdf) suggests that `saveAccount:withCompletionHandler:` attempts to perform `OAuth` itself:

> If the account type supports authentication and the account is not authenticated, the account is authenticated
>   using its credentials. If the authentication is successful, the account is saved; otherwise, it is not saved.

I find that very strange since there is no way for the user to authenticate directly with the server by inputting username/password.

I also tried to initialize `ACAccountCredential` with my application's consumer key and consumer secret, with the same result (failed with `NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.`)

Any guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same trouble adding a Twitter account with ACAccount. However, I was able to create a Twitter account with ACAccount successfully using an authorized OAuth Access token and Access token secret, not the Consumer key and Consumer secret. (dev.twitter.com/apps->Twitter->OAuth->OAuth Setting-->Access token and Access token secret) This means that you still have to use an OAuth library to get an authorized Access token and Access token secret when the user is adding a Twitter account.

Update: You can see how Twitter recommends that you migrate existing accounts to iOS5 system accounts [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/migrating-tokens-core-accounts). That link provided me with the best example of how to add an ACAccount.