# Proper way how to use hardcoded twitter account in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

Short version of the question is this: is there any way on iOS (using iOS5 twitter framework or some 3rd party library) to do what is described on this page for other platforms: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples

For example in c# one can use the following using 3rd party library:

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.ConsumerKey = "Consumer Key";
tokens.ConsumerSecret = "Consumer Secret";
tokens.AccessToken = "Access Key";
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "Access Secret";

TwitterStatusCollection homeTimeline = TwitterStatus.GetHomeTimeline(tokens);
```

which is basically what I need.

Here is some additional info on what I am trying to do in case it is relevant:

I would like to create application, which access one certain twitter account  and present some of these tweets. I have of course access to this account (read-only access is therefore fine).
So far, I have also created the twitter app using https://dev.twitter.com/apps site. There I have generated the auth token and secret and get the consumer key and secret. Now I would like to use it in the app (I hope all of these are permanent unless I delete them so I can hard code them in the app?).

I came across this SO question: [Error creating twitter ACAccount on iOS5: NSURLErrorDomain error -1012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224835/error-creating-twitter-acaccount-on-ios5-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012) , where the guy wanted to do something similar probably and was recommended to use this:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/migrating-tokens-core-accounts .
For me it did not work and I think it is not the proper way of doing what I need anyway.

I become to feel more and more that I am trying to do something easy in conceptually bad way :)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe XAuth is what you need
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth

Comment: @Guo Thanks Guo for your reply. The xAuth allows me only to receive the access token and token secret. However, I would like to find out what is the next step. Ideally in a form of some high level library, similar to the one available in C# I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I want to do the exact same thing as you, and everybody talks about the account stored in the phone. I don't want to use that account, I want to use my own app tokens! Thanks!

Comment: @Jan Unfortunatelly not. The devlopment of the app was dropped after we found out that the API of Twitter is not that great - at least for what we need. So the issue of the authenication was not researched after that.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600621/iphone-twitter-api-get-users-followers-following/11601077#11601077) which shows you how to do authentication and requests with Twitter using the built in iOS 5 Twitter framework.