# Getting user's information after OAuth login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to get user's info. After OAuth I send this request:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Public Timeline: %@", JSON);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
    NSLog(@"json = %@", JSON);}];
[operation start];
```

But got an error: `{"error":"Could not authenticate you.","request":"\/1\/account\/verify_credentials.json"}` Why I can't get access to information even after login in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't attached the OAuth token to the request. You're just sending a request with that URL string.

You might to have a look [AFOAuth2Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) which provides a neat extension to AFNetworking for doing authorized requests on Twitter.

Alternatively, you can use the built in iOS 5+ Twitter API, [I wrote an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600621/iphone-twitter-api-get-users-followers-following/11601077#11601077) for another SO post that shows you how exactly to do this - and it's super easy :)

If you need to implement OAuth from scratch, please see: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, but how can I send request if I don't know username, password and other staff for user which login in through OAuth?

Comment: Your example using account from device preferences, but what about user login in through application?

Comment: Well, you need to implement Twitter OAuth in your application. I have updated the answer with a link to this.

Comment: @runmad : AFOAuth2Client is for OAuth 2 and Twitter uses OAuth 1.0a.