# On iOS how can I get the list of followers that the user is also following on Twitter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

In my app I would like to send a direct message to Twitter friends to invite to use the app. In order to send a direct message I need the target person to follow the user. How ever I don't want to list all the followers but only the followers that the user is also following. Is there a way to get this list in iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine)

**#import "FHSTwitterEngine.h"**

Add **SystemConfiguration.framework**

Write following code to your viewDidLoad(for oauth login)

```
UIButton *logIn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
logIn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[logIn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[logIn addTarget:self action:@selector(showLoginWindow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:logIn];

[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"Xg3ACDprWAH8loEPjMzRg" andSecret:@"9LwYDxw1iTc6D9ebHdrYCZrJP4lJhQv5uf4ueiPHvJ0"];
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];


 - (void)showLoginWindow:(id)sender {
UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];
    NSString *username = [FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine].authenticatedUsername;
    NSLog(@"user name is :%@",username);
    if (username.length > 0) {
        [self listResults];
    }
}];
     [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
 - (void)listResults {

NSString *username = [FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine].authenticatedUsername;
NSMutableDictionary *   dict1 = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFriendsForUser:username isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];

//  NSLog(@"====> %@",[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"] );        // Here You get all the data
NSMutableArray *array=[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"];
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSLog(@"names:%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. this code getting the followers and following names

```
 ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
 ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
 [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account
        if (accounts.count > 0)
        {
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

            for(ACAccount *t in accounts)
            {
                if([t.username isEqualToString:username])
                {
                    twitterAccount = t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username], @"screen_name", @"-1", @"cursor", nil]];
            [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
            // Making the request
            [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Check if we reached the reate limit
                    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                        NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                        return;
                    }
                    // Check if there was an error
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        return;
                    }
                    // Check if there is some response data
                    if (responseData) {
                        NSError *error = nil;
                        NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


                    }
                });
            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No access granted");
    }
}];
```

Comment: need more information use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600621/iphone-twitter-api-get-users-followers-following

Comment: what is username?? and how to get it??

Comment: you can get the username from here: twitterAccount.username

Comment: How to get more than 20 results? I'm using updating cursor value to point to next page, and get the data but after 10, 12 pages I'm getting "Rate limit reached" status code 429, what's the optimal way to do this?

Comment: you should set count=200, where 200 is the max limit returned count and 20 is the default

Comment: Is there any way to fetch followers without using ACAccountStore?