# How to do login with TWRequest in a user friendly manner?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, twrequest

After having a look at Apple `TWRequest` class (and example), **I was surprised it has no possibilities for presenting a user with a login screen.** The only way is to check if a user has entered its credentials with `[TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]` and if no then give a message like

**"Hey, you have manually to go to settings->twitter and enter the credentials. Then you should find and open our app manually and continue on"**

I'm wondering does anybody use such crap functionality :) For example, `Facebook iOS SDK 3` has implemented **Single Sign On (SSO)** that **opens Safari with Facebook login screen and returns to your app after login...** I guess I will need to fallback to old styled twitter integration with a lot of 3rd party stuff.

ps. I would give a try to **ShareKit** but I need to integrate my app with **google+** which is not currently supported in ShareKit.

Comment: Not sure why you think that a centralised credential handling is in any way crappy. The same mechanics are used for email-accounts etc.

Comment: Look at Accounts.framework documentation (class ACAccount). You don't have to use canSendTweet.

Comment: @Till, I'm not against centralized way, I'm just against user unfriendliness. For example, Facebook iOS SDK 3 has implemented Single Sign On (SSO) that opens Safari with Facebook login screen and returns to your app after login. A user is guided during login  when using Facebook classes. But it's not the case for TWRequest that forces a user to take care of his first login himself.

Comment: An ACAccount object encapsulates information about a user account stored in the Accounts database. You can **create** and retrieve accounts using an ACAccountStore object. The ACAccountStore object provides an interface to the persistent Accounts database. For each user, all account objects belong to a single ACAccountStore object.

Comment: @Till, I'm not sure will it be sufficient to use native Twitter and Account frameworks for creating a user. The post indicates a user can't be created using twitter consumer key and consumer secret (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224835/error-creating-twitter-acaccount-on-ios5-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012). You still need to use OAuth to get an authorized Access token and Access token secret.